# discrepancy in batch script output via WMIC

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to execute a batch script from a remote server using WMIC and getting the output attached is 'WMIC_Output.JPG'

[image: WMIC_Output]

Output i am seeing from the command is not accurate. when i run the same script on actual server i can see the correct output. Please refer to attached screenshot 'Output.JPG'
[image: Output]

Now i assume script being executed remotely is giving me process ID and the script exit status.

Please let me know WMIC parameters/switches to be included to get the required output.

-Abhi

Comment: is it possible to redirect the output to a file and then read it?

Comment: Put a "cd" command in the batch file. It will probably show you that you are in some directory like "C:\Windows\System32" or some such default directory. You may have to modify your bat file so that it lands in the right directory before execution begins.

Comment: @blackpen I am changing directory in the script before executing the command
cd C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\
C:
aws command ....

-Abhi

Comment: @npocmaka I did redirect output as suggested to a file ..aws command.. >> E:\SiteScope\logs\AWSOutput.txt, but the file didn't get created. So it means the script is not being executed remotely via wmic. When i run the script on the actual server i can see contents in the output file. Any further suggestions/inputs on how to make wmic run the script? - Abhi

Comment: @AbhinandanAithal, Try to run a batch file with single command `echo ok` and redirect that to a file. If that doesn't work, then you have a problem in permissions to create a file (to write) or problem in permissions in executing a batch file. Post the command and the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Execute it by specifying `/k` opiton for the `cmd.exe`. You also need to protect the spaces in the name of batch file by using quotes.

```
C:\Users\user>wmic /node:localhost process call create 'cmd.exe  /k "C:\\Users\user\\AWS__APIGATEWAY - 4xerror - Windows.bat" '
```

**Details:**

When you execute ...

```
C:\Users\user>wmic /node:localhost process call create "cmd.exe  C:\\Users\user\\AWS__APIGATEWAY - 4xerror - Windows.bat"
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 2192;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

The `cmd.exe` needs `/k` option. When we add '/k' option ...

```
C:\Users\user>wmic /node:localhost process call create "cmd.exe  /k C:\\Users\user\\AWS__APIGATEWAY - 4xerror - Windows.bat"
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 4064;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

and shows this in a popped-up window:

```
'C:\\Users\user\\AWS__APIGATEWAY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

When we put quotes around the batch file name, it executes correctly and produces output in a new cmd window:

```
C:\Users\user>wmic /node:localhost process call create 'cmd.exe  /k "C:\\Users\user\\AWS__APIGATEWAY - 4xerror - Windows.bat" '
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 5788;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Not sure where i am going wrong.
C:\Users\a-Abhinandan.aithal>wmic /node:<remote_server> process call create 'cmd.exe /k "E:\\SiteScope\\scripts.remote\\AWS_APIGATEWAY - 4xxerror - Win
dows.bat"'
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 5128;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};

-Abhi

Comment: If you replace the contents of your gateway script with a one liner test command, does that work successfully?

Answer (score 0):

as npocmaka told you sendoutput to a file and then read it. With `wmic` escaping is hard. please try

```
set "fileout=c:\....\output.txt"
wmic /node:dnvprdsis11.....org process call create "cmd /c E:\\sitescope\\...Windows.bat > \"%fileout%\"" >NUL 2>NUL 
ping localhost -n 2 -w 300 >NUL
if exist "%fileout%" type "%fileout%"
```

the `... > \"%fileout%\ ..."` may also need escaping  `... ^> \"%fileout%\" ...`